# (Intellij) "unclosed character literal" and "illegal character '\u00a7'" when compiling

Tags: java, ascii

Im trying to compile the '§' character into a char (`char c = '§'`) but when i try to build, it says in the build output "`Unclosed character literal`" and "`Illegal character: '\u00a7'`" followed by "`Unclosed character literal`" again. If i put the character into a String (`String s = "§"`) it works fine. But when i print it to console, it prints the 'Â' character (which it shouldn't)

In another java project, i can use the '§' character fine and compile normally, and it works as intended; printing it to console shows nothing (which is normal, because it's used as an escape character for colouring the text). That project (and the current one) don't use "BOM" in intellij, and they both use UTF8 encoding

Does anyone know how to fix this? thanks:)

Comment: The encoding of the text and the encoding accepted by the compiler are different. If your text encoding is UTF-8, you should compile it with `javac -encoding UTF-8 ...`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How I could reproduce that error:

- created a new `Test.java` with UTF-8 encoding (default)
- added main with `char c = '§';` and print it
- run `Test.main()`

no errors, as expected.

---

So I tried:

- created second file `Test1.java` and changed to `ISO-8859-1` encoding
- added main method with just a print command
- run `Test1.java`

this time I got the reported error but for `Test.java` (still encoded as UTF-8)

Looks like IDEA uses the encoding of first file for the whole source code.

---

Solutions:

- make sure all files are encoded with UTF-8; and/or
- use `javac -encoding UTF-8 ...` as [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68979187/intellij-unclosed-character-literal-and-illegal-character-u00a7-when-co#comment121910960_68979187) by [saka1029](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4910279/saka1029)

Comment: Im not sure why, but converting the file from UTF8 to UTF16 and back to UTF8 somehow fixed it. So it might've just been a bug

Comment: May I ask how you did this conversation?

Comment: There's an option on the bottom right of the intellij window which lets you select the file's encoding. I don't fully remember what i did, but i'd assume you just change it to UTF16, modify the file and save, then go back to UTF8 and it should work

Answer (score 0):

For me, when editing, I see the message of IDEA that recognizes Japanese characters and I click OK to set the default display to "Encoding windows-31j". During the build process, the system reads the file again according to "Encoding windows-31j", leading to an error. How to fix: Force IDEA to build with UTF-8 Encoding like the [following image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9e05.png)

With you, please change it to "-encoding UTF-16", if UTF8 fails

Answer (score -1):

Use Java's Character: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html

You can retrieve the character through charValue().

Also, make sure you're using the encoding scheme (eg UTF-16) that supports your character.

Comment: Im fairly certain the § char is specified in UTF8 so i probably won't need UTF16. And the other problem is, i also use the character in strings (e.g "§7[§bColourful§3Text§7]"), so i'd have to use a StringBuilder in that case. But, my other java projects use intellij's default settings as well as this one, so i'm not sure why its not working for this project specifically